# Quicktime Video not playing on Google Chrome even after installing plug-in

Tags: video, plugins, web, quicktime, web-services

Even after downloading QuickTime for Windows from Apple website , the video on the following URL still resists to play.

http://www.mhvt.net/quicktime/eng/vtc/affiliate_spam/folder_permission.php

Comment: Verify the Quicktime Plug-in is enabled ( https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2445742?hl=en )

Comment: @Ramhound : its showing it as Enabled , I guess there's a problem with the video itself which is uploaded on the given URL, is it playing on your sys?

Comment: I don't have Quicktime installed because of its a horrible product.

Comment: @Ramhound : is there any other way to play that video ?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: @Ramhound : yeah...in IE8 also the video cannot be played...its just showing a white background in the player , the play/pause buttons are there but none of them seem to work, i guess the video's corrupt...!

Comment: Try to play something from [itunes](http://trailers.apple.com/) this would test the plugin and verify it is plugin issue or video.

Comment: It doesn't play on mac either. Something is broken in the [original video](http://www.mhvt.net/quicktime/eng/00/internet_security/folder_permission_2364411023r.mov).